# Shrinking site's size by removing pages from sitemap and from internal links

Tags: seo, googlebot, sitemap, sitelinks

We are an eCommerce site with about 50,000 pages. We decided to focus on about 2,000 so google will crawl our site better.
We planning to remove 48,000 pages from the sitemaps and from the site links, so it won't be accessible through the site.
The pages will still be accessible if going them directly. 
Our concern is that these 'orphan pages' will damage our SEO. Are that many 'orphan pages' can harm our site?
Redirection is not an option since we will use some of the pages in the future.

Comment: I don't have any experience with this directly, but I found this article that says that orphan pages are really bad for SEO: https://www.gobluemedia.com/blog/orphan-pages/

Comment: Deindex those 48,000 pages using meta robots tag in <head></head> section of each and every pages or use canonical tag to all those pages and point them to relevant page which will tell Google to not index those pages but they can crawl. Then only it will not harm your previous SEO and future SEO.

Comment: It's unavoidable and natural, with ecommerce to have a large number of urls. As it was mentioned above, "orphan pages" are no good. I cannot picture how your website will be structured if you intend to make those 48k pages orphans. It's pretty simple with commerce website: home page > product category > product. Just make sure that the category pages and product pages are described properly, in other words have some value.

Comment: This is my opinion: A better way to focus on the 2000 pages is to improve the content and quality of those pages rather than reducing the importance of the other 48,000 pages.

Answer (score 1):

> We are an eCommerce site with about 50,000 pages.

For an eCommerce website this is normal, as per [sitmap.org](https://www.sitemaps.org/faq.html), a sitemap can have 50,000 URL and size upto 50MB.

Therefore it's suggested to use indexed sitemap, which enable you to use 50,000 sitemaps, which is equal to [50,000 x 50,000 = 2,50,00,00,000 URLs].

> Q: How big can my Sitemap be?
>
> Sitemaps should be no larger than 50MB (52,428,800 bytes) and can contain a maximum of 50,000 URLs. These limits help to ensure that your web server does not get bogged down serving very large files. This means that if your site contains more than 50,000 URLs or your Sitemap is bigger than 50MB, you must create multiple Sitemap files and use a [Sitemap index](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.php#index) file. You should use a Sitemap index file even if you have a small site but plan on growing beyond 50,000 URLs or a file size of 50MB. A Sitemap index file can include up to 50,000 Sitemaps and must not exceed 50MB (52,428,800 bytes). You can also use gzip to compress your Sitemaps.
>
> Q: My site has tens of millions of URLs; can I somehow submit only those that have changed recently?
>
> You can list the URLs that change frequently in a small number of Sitemaps and then use the [lastmod](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.php#lastmoddef) tag in your [Sitemap index](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.php#index) file to identify those Sitemap files. Search engines can then incrementally crawl only the changed Sitemaps.

I'll recommend you to go with indexed sitemap instead removing pages, from sitemap.

Removing page from sitemap will not hurt your SEO anyway and it's not the right solution, Google will crawl these pages as they exist.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the size of the sitemap.  They are trying to better focus their site on their core competencies.  Just list the products that they know a lot about.

Comment: " We planning to remove 48,000 pages from the sitemaps and from the site links, so it won't be accessible through the site. " - this says that they want to keep URL but want to remove from sitemap file, which is not the right solution.

Moreover they want to use these pages in future, therefore no need to deindex them, therefore I've explained the scenario. Is there anything I need to update, please feel free to suggest, I'll edit and update the answer.

Comment: You have a comment that you should find a way to add to this answer.   I like your suggestion of noindexing the removed pages.

Comment: @DeepakMathur as Stephen mentioned we are not concerned with the size of the sitemap. Our goal is to let Google focus on just 2,000 pages so they will be updated on Google more frequently. In the current situation, Google doesn't crawl many important pages because it 'wastes' its time on the unimportant pages.

Comment: If you think those 48,000 pages are not worth to let crawled you have to put meta tag <meta name="robots" content="noindex"> or you can do it by HTTP header.